# Does Natron work on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux

I first wanted to install it from AUR BUT I get errors like `pacman failed to ...`, I then downloaded the [portable version](https://natrongithub.github.io/) and  with the portable version of Natron, If I run it with `optirun` and click on shadertory, sometimes I get this:

[image]

sometimes don't. I can select shader from `Load from Preset` despite the error and inside natron screen shader works fine. If I then try to add a write node and save it as `.mp4`, I don't see any changes in `File type` as I type in `filename.mp4`:

[image]

drop down list there is actually empty. If I hit save, I get this:

[image]

To locate plugins manually I did this in `Edit > Preferences > Plugins`:

[image]

and restarted Natron but that didn't help. I didn't test without `optirun`.

Any way to solve this problem?

---

**EDIT**

I get all those errors except `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` if I install the non-portable version and it actually doesn't work without `optirun`. Here's what I get if I run it from `Konsole` without `optirun`:

```
[emon@haque ~]$ Natron2/Natron
Natron Version 2.3.14
Copyright (C) 2013-2018 INRIA and Alexandre Gauthier-Foichat
>>>Use the --help or -h option to print usage.<<<
couldn't open library /home/emon/Natron2/Plugins/OFX/Natron/Arena.ofx.bundle/Contents/Linux-x86-64/Arena.ofx because /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
Caught segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) from thread Main(0x24619d0), faulty address is 0x366a0 from 0x366a0
Backtrace:
[emon@haque ~]$
```

When I run it with `optirun`, I get these on `Konsole`:

```
[emon@haque ~]$ optirun Natron2/Natron
Natron Version 2.3.14
Copyright (C) 2013-2018 INRIA and Alexandre Gauthier-Foichat
>>>Use the --help or -h option to print usage.<<<
couldn't open library /home/emon/Natron2/Plugins/OFX/Natron/Arena.ofx.bundle/Contents/Linux-x86-64/Arena.ofx because /usr/lib/libcairo.so.2: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
couldn't open library /home/emon/Natron2/Plugins/OFX/Natron/IO.ofx.bundle/Contents/Linux-x86-64/IO.ofx because /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
Info: init.py script not loaded (this is not an error)
Info: initGui.py script not loaded (this is not an error)
```

while it's running.

Comment: The AUR PKGBUILD has some 'depends' that are not available with pacman, but they are also in the AUR: `openfx-arena` `openfx-gmic` `openfx-io` `openfx-misc`.

Have you tried installing those, and then `natron`?

Comment: @ejjl, I'd started with `openfx-io` and got that error `pacman failed to ...`. After installing Natron, it looks like problem is in `harfbuzz` and `cairo`, see the **EDIT** part.